# PHP gives unexpected [ - but why?

Tags: php, datetime, if-statement

having strange trouble with this:

```
date_parse('2014-08-26')['hour']
```

It works on a php command line.

But this throws an error:

```
if(date_parse('2014-08-26')['hour']){ echo "works";}
```

*syntax error, unexpected '['*

Why is that? The result should be any number between 0 and 23 or nothing, nothing would it be in this case.

---

EDIT: yes, I am on PHP 5.3.14

Comment: Please note that versions of PHP older than 5.4 can not access array attributes from a function return value directly. You have to store the function return value in a new variable and access the array from that variable.

Comment: Version difference between command line and web server PHP.

Comment: Sometimes depending on how / where you installed PHP you can end up running a different version of PHP on the command line than when via Apache

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER you were the first and provided the right answer, so, feel free to make your comment an actual answer, I'll accept it, because it works and explains why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that versions of PHP older than 5.4 [can not access array attributes from a functions return value directly](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-102). You have to store the functions return value in a new variable and access the array from that variable.

So this code

```
if(date_parse('2014-08-26')['hour']){ echo "works";}
```

only works on PHP 5.4 and higher. If you run a PHP version lower then 5.4 your code should look like this:

```
$parseResult = date_parse('2014-08-26');

if($parseResult['hour']) { echo "works"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Before version 5.4, PHP didn't allow you to dereference elements of arrays returned from function calls without using a temporary variable:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-102

Answer (score 1):

You must be using below 5.4 version of PHP. If so than please use the latest version of php as the version below 5.4 does not allow brackets `[]`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$cond = date_parse('2014-08-26')['hour'];
if($cond)
{ 
 echo "works";
}
```

Hope this works

Comment: sorry, but no - the first line gives the same error!